# Use onMouseEnter on a single element within .map iteration in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, for-loop, next.js

I am stuck trying to implement a hover action over a list of items returned from a .map array. I want the hover to affect just one element and it instead affects all. Here is my code.

```
import { MDBTable, MDBTableHead, MDBTableBody, MDBCol, MDBCard, MDBCardBody } from "mdbreact";
import { Paper, Box } from '@material-ui/core';
import { withStyles, makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { motion } from 'framer-motion'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'


const packageDetails = [...]  
    
export default () => {
    let [elevation, setElevation] = useState(1);

    useEffect(() => {
        
    })
    
    return(
    <Box className="container pt-3 mt-5 mb-5 ">
        <h1 className="text-center pb-5">NOTRE TABLEAU DE PRIX</h1>
        <Box className="row">
        
        {packageDetails.map( (packageDetail, index) => 
        
        <div  className="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 mb-5 ">
        <Paper  elevation={elevation} className="single-table" onMouseEnter={() => setElevation(prevElevation => 5)} onMouseLeave={()=> setElevation(prevElevation => 2)}>
        <MDBTable>
            <MDBTableHead>
                <tr className="package-name-holder">
                    <th className="text-uppercase text-center">{packageDetail.name}</th>
                </tr>
            </MDBTableHead>
                <MDBTableBody>
                    <tr>
                    <th>{packageDetail.price} FCFA/AN</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>{packageDetail.space}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>{packageDetail.bandwidth}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>{packageDetail.domain}</td>
                    </tr>
               
                </MDBTableBody>
        </MDBTable>
        </Paper>
        </div>
        )}
        </Box>
        <style jsx>{`
            .package-name-holder {
                background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(65,176,212,1) 0%, rgba(113,201,219,1) 83%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 100%);
                color: #fff;
            }
        `}</style>
    </Box>
    );
}
```

Any solution is welcome and sorry if I asked poorly.
Thanks.

Comment: Because your function applies in the map function it will effect all the elements. If you want to apply it to an individual element, you should specify it with its id(if there is) or if it is not a dynamic content, I mean if always the same number of elements, you can set it by using the element's index

Comment: Hi @OnerT. thank you very much. It is the best solution but I don't know the approach to take and make it possible. Any hints?

Comment: Can you share the ingredients of packageDetails array? what are its contents in the DB ? are you using MongoDB or SQL or any API, service maybe?

Comment: @OnerT. I can't add the content of packageDetails as the site complains of too much code. packageDetails is an array of objects in the same file.

Comment: ok just share the code of first two or three objects in the array

Comment: @OnerT. ```const packageDetails = [
    {
        name: "Starter",
        price: 20000,
        space: "Espace SSD - 10GB",
        bandwidth: "Bande Passante - 10GB",
        domain: "1 Domaine Gratuit",
        email: "Emails - 10",
        ssl: "SSL Gratuit",
        support: "Support 24/7"
    },
    {
        name: "Standard",
        price: 25000,
        space: "Espace SSD - 30GB",
        bandwidth: "Bande Passante - 30GB",
        domain: "1 Domaine Gratuit",
        email: "Emails - 20",
        ssl: "SSL Gratuit",
        support: "Support 24/7"
    }];```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rely on data in your `packageDetails` array. Thus if you want to use mouse effects on the first element only use something like this:

```
<Paper
  elevation={elevation}
  className="single-table"
  onMouseEnter={index === 0 ? () => setElevation(prevElevation => 5) : () => {}}
  onMouseLeave={index === 0 ? () => setElevation(prevElevation => 2) : () => {}}
>
```

This is just an unoptimized code, for example use `noop` from `lodash` package instead of `() => {}`

Comment: Hi @lazy.lizard, thank you but I want the hover effect to apply on one element each time it is hovered on. I have 4 elements. The current behavior is rather than the effect on one, the effect is on all 4 elements.

Comment: Put `index` to state like `setElevation(index)` and use `elevation={index === elevation ? 1 : 0}` within `Paper`. Don't forget to clear it with `null` value on mouse leave and set default elevation value to `null` too like `useState(null)`

Comment: hi @lazy.lizard yeah I need an explanation. Thanks.

Comment: I have elements=[1,2,3,4], I want to apply shadow effect on each element only when the cursor is hovered on that element. The current behavior is that when I hover on a single element, it applies the shadow I want to all elements not only the one I hovered on like it should be.

Comment: So when you hover a single element all elements must be elevated (hovered), right?

Comment: If so you need to know if **any** of you elements is hovered, so first you must set default value of `elevation` to `false` - `useState(false)`. Then when you hover any element set `elevation` to `true` - `onMouseEnter={() => setElevation(true)}`. Then change `elevation` prop to `elevation={elevation ? 1 : 0}` - it means that if `elevation` in your state is `true` `Paper` receives value `1` that means that component is displayed as _elevated_, otherwise it receives `0` what according to MUI specs displays `Paper` without shadow. Don't forget to set `onMouseLeave={() => setElevation(false)}`.

Comment: thank you very much. No I want that when I hover a single element just that element should be elevated and not all the rest.

Comment: Then see my reply where I speak about putting `index` to state (`setElevation(index)`).